# Do backgroundSubtractor functions in opencv only detect moving objects?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, image-processing

There are some backgroundsubtractor functions in opencv like backgroundsubtractormog2 , backgroundsubtractorGMG and ... . It seems that these functions only detect moving objects in a video.

But I understand from the concept of these functions, that they do some clustering in an image.
Do these functions only detect moving objects? Why? Or am I wrong?

Any help will be appreciated